# How do I install and configure Xdebug/PhpStorm

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to install Xdebug and PhpStorm as per the following:

- I have an iMac that I work form where I just write the PHP scripts.
- I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Server which runs the PHP scripts that I upload to it.

I want to install Xdebug on the Ubuntu Server machine but still use my iMac for writing the scripts, I want to be able to debug my code with Xdebug/PhpStorm from my iMac on my Ubuntu Server.

I have followed several guides and have installed Xdebug properly, `sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug`. I have also edited the php.ini file so that the following text appears in my phpinfo file: "with Xdebug v2.2.3". I added the following lines to my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Then I installed PhpStorm 2017.2 on my iMac. But from here I can't get anything to work.

How do I configure PhpStorm to be able to debug the code that's on my Ubuntu Server? I have SSH on my Ubuntu Server and can connect to my Ubuntu Server with SSH.

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- have a look if you have not seen it yet -- it has many topics covered. 2) *"But from here I can't get anything to work."* What exactly does not work? What's your config from PhpStorm side is? What xdebug log has to say about it? What are you trying to debug -- CLI script or web page? Is your web server/PHP uses right php.ini (on Linux you often have separate config files for CLI and web server). Need details.

Comment: Try to set ´xdebug.remote_autostart = 1´and ´xdebug.remote_enable = 1´